# Run latest MockWebServer with Robolectric and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, robolectric, mockwebserver

Near an year ago I wrote an Android application covered by tests on this tech stack. Now I working on new application and use all latest versions of libs and stuck to pass web request from Robolectric tests to MockWebServer.

The simple version on Junit works fine, but as soon as I convert test into Robolectric test or add subscribeOn\observeOn via new TestScheduler() (equals to Scheulers.immediate() to get response immediately in the same thread) retrofit request doesn't step into MockWebDispatcher.

Here is the code

```
//@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
//@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,
//        sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class ApiTest {

    private MockWebServer server;
    private Api api;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        server = new MockWebServer();
        server.setDispatcher(new AppDispatcher());
        server.start();

        api = getApi(server.url("/").toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallToApi() {
        TestObserver<List<User>> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
        Observable<List<User>> users = api.getUsers()
                .subscribeOn(new TestScheduler())
                .observeOn(new TestScheduler());

        users.subscribe(testObserver);

        testObserver.assertNoErrors();
        testObserver.assertComplete();

        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    private Api getApi(String url) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
```

Build gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1'
testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.9.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3'
```

Any ideas about the root cause of the issue?

I checked my previous and it works fine with this lib set and API tests work well

```
   compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0"
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2'
    testCompile('com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.7.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio', module: 'okio'
    })
```

That's why I assume some changes in behavior introduced in new versions of libraries

Comment: Why do you need Robolectric here? RxJava, Gson and Retorfit should work on JVM without issues

Comment: I write this app to be familiar with tech stack that used on the project I am going to work. For this particular case it should work without robolectric, but for the rest parts of application it should use mobile specific components.